# Access Violation Writing Location c++

Tags: c++, cplex

I am new to c++ and cplex so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Problem:  I am running a column generation code. My code looks like this:

```
CPXENVptr *env = NULL;
CPXLPptr *lp= null;



  //---------COLUMN GENERATION BEGINS--------------------------------------------

   printf("\nStarting column generation.\n");
   num_iterations = 0;
   total_cols_generated = 0;

   while(1)
   {
   // we are about to do another pricing iteration
   num_iterations++;


   // get dual prices

   status=CPXgetpi(env,lp,dual_value,0,num_customers-1);
   if (status)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"CPXgetpi Failed.\n");
      goto TERMINATE;
   }

   // call pricing routine

   printf ("\nPricing iteration %u.\n", num_iterations);

   cols_generated = generate_column(env, lp, num_nodes, num_customers, TT, service_time, start_of_window, end_of_window, out_degree, neighbour, arc_cost, arc_time, dual_value);
   total_cols_generated += cols_generated;

   if (cols_generated == 0)
         break;

   // re-optimize the master problem

   printf("Re-optimising master LP.\n");

    status =  CPXdualopt (env, lp);

   if ( status  ) {
      printf ("Failed to re-optimize master LP.\n");
      getchar();
      goto TERMINATE;
   }

   // get objective value

   status  = CPXgetobjval (env, lp, &lower_bound);
   if ( status ) {
      fprintf (stderr,"Failed to obtain objective value.\n");
      goto TERMINATE;
   }

   // print stuff to screen

    printf ("Current cost of RMP solution is %.3f\n", lower_bound);
    printf ("\nPress a key\n");
    getchar();

} // end while
```

On the second Optimisation (second time going in while ) it gives Access Violation Writing location at  status =  CPXdualopt (env, lp);.

Any idea?

Comment: Are env and lp really NULL pointers? I think you need to post a bit more code. Also post your real code, since the above is not even legal C++.

Comment: "My code looks like this:... " No it doesn't, or you wouldn't even *compile* much-less run to an access violation. Try posting **real code** that demonstrates the **real** problem.

Comment: If the program is too large, make a smaller program that has the same problem and update this question with that code.  We can't assume that `...` isn't a bug, and none of the code you posted produces an access violation.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation for `CPXgetpi`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefcallablelibrary%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2FCPXgetpi.html):

> `CPXCENVptr` env
>
> The pointer to the CPLEX environment as returned by `CPXopenCPLEX()`.
>
> `CPXCLPptr` lp
>
> A pointer to a CPLEX problem object as returned by `CPXcreateprob()`.

You aren't passing pointers to these objects.  You're passing `NULL` instead for both of them.

The [documentation for `CPXdualopt`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefcallablelibrary%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2FCPXdualopt.html) shows the same problem.